# Teamcity: versioned settings, build templates and different VCS roots

Tags: teamcity

I'm trying to ensure that my entire build configuration in Teamcity is under configuration management.
But, I'm also sharing a build template across different projects (with different VCS roots). The template is used in different sub-projects in Teamcity, where the VCS root is specified.
So, when I enable Versioned Settings for the project, only the specific settings are added, not the contents of the template. And as the template are defined in the root project, I can't enable Versioned Settings at this level.
Any suggestions?

BR
Rasmus

Answer (score 0):

Create or move VCS-roots in Root Project or parent project,

if you change anything in above vcs-roots you can apply it to one or all configuration, there is an option in the last section of vcs-root setting looks like

[image]

Comment: Thank for your reply.
I might not have been particularly clear though:
I have multiple roots (with different projects) that all build using the same template (same maven build steps, profiles etc.). Obviously, the build configs using this template each use their "own" VCS-root, so I would like the entire effice build configuration (including what derived from the template) to be consolidated in the VCS-root. Only that way do I have the build config configuration managed.

BR
Rasmus